# How to distinguish between continuity in fixed point theory and analysis

Tags: analysis, functions, continuity, terminology, fixed-point-theorems

Hi I was trying to describe a function (see picture).

[image]

I want to say that it is discontinuous from an analytic point of view. Because
$ \lim_{x \to -1^- }f(x)  \ne \lim_{x \to -1^+ }f(x) $

Now from a fixed point theory point of view this function is continuous. Because sup(f(x)) = f(sup(x)) is true for every x in any subset X of the functions domain. Which makes it continuous.

The terminology is confusing because the function is discontinuous from an analytic point of view but continuous in the context of fixed point theory. Is there any way/terminology to distinguish between the two?

Comment: where did you see that definition of continuity. You say fixed-point theory, but can you be more specific? Fixed-point theorems are often formulated in general metric spaces, where supremum doesn’t even make sense. Also, by $\sup f(x)$ I assume you mean $\sup_{x\in \Bbb{R}}f(x)$, which in this case is $\infty$; on the other hand, $\sup_{x\in\Bbb{R}}x=\infty$, which isn’t in the domain of $f$. Sure, you can say $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$, but this is different. You can’t really write the equality you wrote (no good definition should have this problem).

Comment: @peek-a-boo I will edit my post to specify this. The definition of continuity, I mentioned is quite common, I never really bothered to ask in which structure its defined but as it is regularly written I would define it as U. My problem however is indeed situation in $  \mathbb{R} $. The thing you are forgetting is for the function to be continuous your choice in x in case of sup(f(x)) = f(sup(x)) is arbitrary as long as x is the domain of the function, and thus need to apply for every x in every subset X. Now this is indeed not stated explicitly in my post apologies for the confusion.

Comment: this is the terminology: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-continuity

Comment: thx that just what I needed! If you write an answer I will upvote and approve.